# Faking a module in angular 2 test

Tags: unit-testing, angular, ionic-framework, jasmine

I have a function in angular 2 service which I would like to test.

`service.ts`

```
upload(){
  let file = new Transfer();
  file.upload(myfile).then( // my callback );
}
```

I would like to mock `Transfer` in my test using `jasmine`. I tried this in my

`sevice.spec.ts`

`import { TransferMock as Transfer } from '../mocks/mocks'` to mock it. But it is not working. This is how my test is instantiated .

```
describe('authentication service' , () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    auth = new Service(<any>new HttpMock(), <any>new StorageMock())
  });
  it('initialize authentication',() => {
    expect(auth).not.toEqual(null);
    auth.upload('file'); //it fails here
  });
})
```

**edit**

**`Transfer` is not injected in the service.** Only one function uses `Transfer` . So not injecting  can reduce the initial loading time of the app i guess(would be happy to know other opinions) . So I would like to know if there is anyway to mock if its constructed this way ?

**edit**

Although I had accepted Martin's answer as it is the best practice, it has one issue which can happen when you use `ionic-native` plugins.If the plugin doesnt have browser support it can fail. In this case it happened when I inject it, with error `FileTransfer is not defined` . So I am back again, looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to provide a mock for a class in a test, you need to inject the class in your implementation.

In your `ngModule` add Transfer to your providers. Then simply inject it into your service.

Then in your test you can use `{ provide: Transfer, useClass: TransferMock }` in your `TestBed` providers.

**Update**

The primary purpose of Dependency Injection is to make code testable and to allow mocking - faking - stubbing of services.

**Update**

With Dependancy Injection you can configure a different set of providers for different environments.

For example, if you are running your application in the browser, and in a native mobile environment you can swap out your configuration.

In your module you could have something like this:

```
const TRANSFER_PROVIDER: any;

if (environment.browser) {
  TRANSFER_PROVIDER = Transfer;
} else {
  TRANSFER_PROVIDER = { provide: Transfer, useClass: NativeTransfer }
}

...
providers: [ TRANSFER_PROVIDER ]
```

NativeTransfer could be a simple stub that does nothing but prevent errors, or it could let the user know that this feature is not supported in their browser.

Comment: Thanks Martin for quick reply. ``Transfer`` is not injected in my service as I did mention in my question. Only one function uses ``Transfer`` . So not injecting  can reduce the initial loading time i guess(?) . So I would like to know if there is anyway to mock if its constructed this way ?

Comment: No. You should do it the way as mentioned by Martin. There is no drawback injecting Transfer into your service... even if it used only in one method. This is a common pattern.

Comment: @raj You will not see a performance hit by using Dependancy Injection. Instead you will have the benefit of testable code.

Comment: Thanks philippo, martin . I understand that injecting ``Transfer`` is the best way to go. So I have rewritten it that way.  Still I would like to know if there is any way to mock ``Transfer`` constructor . It can be helpful when working with a framework which doesnt have DI.

Comment: @raj You can use an external library like Inversify with frameworks that do not have DI built in. Many React devs use Inversify along with Typescript. DI is just one pattern for implementing Inversion of Control, for very simple apps that you want to test you can manually wire up dependancies in main() or use a technique called "poor man's dependancy injection" where you new up instances if they are not passed in the constructor, allowing you to pass in a mock implementation in the test.

Comment: @Martin I have updated the question as injection caused another issue.

Comment: @Martin I do not see a way to check if enviornment is browser or mobile . Can you shed more light into it?