# FileTransfer is not defined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using `Transfer` plugin in my ionic 2 app for sending files. While testing the app, I had difficulty in mocking `Transfer`. Please take a look into this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41800772/faking-a-module-in-angular-2-test) to understand the context . After that discussion , I decided to inject `Transfer` in my service.

So I added `Transfer` in my providers in `app.module.ts`.And injected it into my service.

`constructor( public transfer: Transfer){}`

But this leads to an error. `FileTransfer is not defined`. I guess its because there is no browser support for this plugin. So I am in a tough spot, I do not know how I can make working testable code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In ionic cordova plugin are not supported for browser Because the browser cant access native api of the os so you need to develop the app and deply it in your Android or ios device .

Comment: check out the following link same problem is there also    https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/filetransfer-is-not-defined/11197/3

Comment: I understand it. But not sure how to test it.