# Dependency injection of modules which are not browser supported

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using `Transfer` plugin from `ionic-native` in my app. I would like to inject it into the app so that testing becomes easier. In `app.module.ts`

`providers: [Transfer]`

But `Transfer` is a cordova plugin which is not  browser supported. So this would fail in development and test. So I would like to mock the plugin if it is in browser . Here is a mock  on how I would like to implement it.

```
const TRANSFER_PROVIDER: any;

if (environment.browser) {
  TRANSFER_PROVIDER = Transfer;
} else {
  TRANSFER_PROVIDER = { provide: Transfer, useClass: NativeTransfer }
}

...
providers: [ TRANSFER_PROVIDER ]
```

But how can I check if its in browser or not in `ionic 2` ? Or Is there any other way to implement this logic?

Comment: How is this question different from your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853681/filetransfer-is-not-defined ?

Comment: This question is essentially the solution to that problem. But I need to know how to implement it. I could have avoided the same example and just asked " How to know the platform of an app ? ".  But this gives a much better idea about the context.